# How cache:clear command works in Symfony2 framework

Tags: symfony, command-line

How the cache clear command works in Symfony2? I am trying to understand the mechanism behind running below command :

> php app/console cache:clear --no-warmup --env=dev

Comment: You might want to check this file: \Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\CacheClearCommand.php

Comment: Are you asking about commands in general or this particular command and how cache clearing and warmup works?

Comment: @1ed The particular command, how cache clearing and warmup works ..

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will help if you haven't seen it yet;

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/index.html

Or look at this file: `\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\CacheClearCommand.php` like @hasumedic mentioned in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The [symfony/console](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/index.html) is a powerful component that provides a way to build CLI commands.

Commands can be used as cron jobs, configuration generators, data importing/exporting, background jobs, ...

A useful feature, the [Question](http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/Console/Question/Question.html) and its [QuestionHelper](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/helpers/questionhelper.html) that provides interaction with the CLI user through dialogs and questions.

To register a new command in your Symfony application, follow the [How create console command](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/console_command.html) guide.

The console is particularly suited to be used as standalone component, combined with doctrine or any other PHP libraries.

To understand how a specific command works, look at [the corresponding class in the API](http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Command/CacheClearCommand.html).

**Update**

I just saw your comment, but the title is misleading ("How console commands works", should be "how cache:clear command works").

The `cache:clear` command juste remove the old cache directory and re-build a new one.

Comment: @Ankiig Why my edit caused you unaccept the answer ?